# Connect to server - password syntax (symbols) confusing the expression

Tags: macos, unix, nas

I'd like to connect to my local server using the following expression in Finder/Go/Connect to server: `afp://username:password@serverIP.local`

My password is using characters which I'm pretty sure are confusing the readability of this expression (e.g. @, %, perhaps other characters) - and I know nothing about UNIX. Say if my password was `p@s$w%rd`, the expression would look as such `afp://username:p@s$w%rd@serverIP.local` but because there is an `@` it will confuse its readability. However, I don't want to compromise on the server's security and would like to keep freedom of syntax for my login credentials.

Is there a way to isolate the password syntax in a way to tell my computer to read the password from a specific input to an output?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, you can always add additional questions if required.

Comment: I have no idea whether this would work, but how about [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which would make your p/w `p%40s%24w%25rd`

Comment: It actually worked!!!! brilliant thanks a lot!

Comment: Let me drop that in as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure whether this would work, but after comments it appears it does…

Use [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) like you see on web addresses, where potentially confusing symbols are replaced by a percentage sign followed by a hexadecimal number, as this table...

[image]

So the initial `p@s$w%rd` would become `p%40s%24w%25rd`